# Fabric crash at startup

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

My app crashed at this line inside onCreate() function

```
 Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

The device is SAMSUNG SM-G313 HZ, running 4.4.2
I've reported to their Twitter dev forum, but my post is automarked as spam.

Anybody knows a workaround?

This is the `onCreate` function:

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        graph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules());

        ImageLoaderConfiguration imageLoaderConfiguration =
                ImageLoaderConfiguration.
                        createDefault(getApplicationContext());
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(imageLoaderConfiguration);

        MMX.init(this, R.raw.initfile);
        MMX.registerListener(new MessageEventListenerForLockScreen(this));


        Intent intent = new Intent(getString(R.string.wake_up_key));
        MMX.registerWakeupBroadcast(intent);

    }
```

I've already declared fabric in AndroidManifest

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="mykeyhere_a1cff923b11afaab1be7b005474d99b912b3"/>
```

Logcat:

```
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime: Process: funride.android.com.rideshare, PID: 16717
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.VerifyError: com/crashlytics/android/core/CrashlyticsCore
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.<init>(Crashlytics.java:29)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at funride.android.com.rideshare.application.CloudBikeApp.onCreate(CloudBikeApp.java:33)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4593)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5344)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:676)
10-06 13:31:53.452 16717-16717/funride.android.com.rideshare E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post your `onCreate` method

Comment: Does it crashes in all devices?

Comment: @AndrewBreen I've updated as requested

Comment: @AbhishekV any device below Android 5.0

Comment: @TungMaiLe  Have you declared crashlytics key in manifest file?

Comment: @AbhishekV Yes I did.

Comment: Did you use the plugin in android studio to add fabric/crashlytics to the app project? And what is the logcat output from the crash?

Comment: @Aegis I've upgraded my Android Studio, so the Fabric plugin is gone.

Comment: Try installing it again and make sure everything is setup correctly. Then you can also change the version number of the dependencies to see if it's a bug in crashlytics

Answer (score 1):

It may be a conflict with third-party libraries, I had a similar crash when using Retrofit2, because Fabric uses an older version of Retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you are using the retrofit 2.0 beta?

Twitter currently uses retrofit 1.8 and won't update until the final release of retrofit 2.0

Discussion that will hopefully be updated when it's fixed can be found here: https://twittercommunity.com/t/java-lang-verifyerror/53974