# Application crash when add Facebook-SDK to gradle

Tags: android, facebook

I have trouble when using `Facebook-SDK`. application crash  when I add library `Facebook SDK`. This is code of me. Please help.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dreamm.karaokepro"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.apptentive:apptentive-android:2.0.1'
    compile 'org.scribe:scribe:1.3.7'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:20041127.091804'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev151-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.3'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.github.rampo.updatechecker:library:2.1.8'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}

build.gradle level project

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This is error when application start

> 01-28 04:13:57.894 1189-1189/com.dreamm.karaokepro E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL       EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            java.lang.VerifyError: com/crashlytics/android/core/CrashlyticsCore
>                                                                            at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.(Crashlytics.java:29)
>                                                                            at com.dreamm.karaokepro.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:22)
>                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

where an error in my code(`Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());`)

```
 public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    private static final int SPLASH_SHOW_TIME = 5000;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        new BackgroundSplashTask().execute();
    }
    private class BackgroundSplashTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SPLASH_SHOW_TIME);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("loaded_info", " ");
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is common http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962007/fabric-crash-at-startup

Comment: Fabric.with(....) Put after setcontent view if required it creates issue.

Comment: I using Retrofit 1.9 but not have result. help me